# iOS 8 requestWhenInUseAuthorization no Popup

Tags: objective-c, geolocation, ios8, privacy

I tried to make my AppProject iOS 8 ready. I had read a lot about

```
[_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

and the entry in plist

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

So I changed all the necessary code lines.

It works fine, but now I have copied my project again from my iOS 7 base to include new features. But when I make the changes for the iOS8 Location Privacy the Popup doesn't appear anymore.

My code worked until I copied.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>tolle sache </string>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>en</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>fapporite.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>BNDL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

and here is my call

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {

        _UserLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]init];
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init]; // initializing locationManager
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // setting the accuracy
        [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; // iOS 8 MUST
        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];  //requesting location updates

        NSLog(@"passed initwithcode");

    }
    return self;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 101):

From the documentation

> NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription (String - iOS) describes the
>   reason why the app accesses the user’s location normally while running
>   in the foreground. Include this key when your app uses location
>   services to track the user’s current location directly. This key does
>   not support using location services to monitor regions or monitor the
>   user’s location using the significant location change service. The
>   system includes the value of this key in the alert panel displayed to
>   the user when requesting permission to use location services.
>
> This key is required when you use the requestWhenInUseAuthorization
>   method of the CLLocationManager class to request authorization for
>   location services. **If the key is not present when you call the
>   requestWhenInUseAuthorization method without including this key, the
>   system ignores your request.**
>
> This key is supported in iOS 8.0 and later. If your Info.plist file
>   includes both this key and the NSLocationUsageDescription key, the
>   system uses this key and ignores the NSLocationUsageDescription key.

Read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW27).

I find that the easiest way to add this key to your info.plist is to right click you info.plist and choose

***Open As->Source Code***

and then add the following in the end **before** `</dict></plist>`

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

If you want you can add a text in between `<string></string>` that describes to the user why you want to use his/hers location. This text will show up under the default text in the alert.

Comment: Perfect Solution for iOS 8!

Comment: @Groot sir i still not able to open alert for enable location

Comment: @Groot, Your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 19):

Try writing a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in Info.plist

Comment: That was the main problem for me. After adding the description, the dialog kept popping up and then immediately disappearing. Fixing that required two changes: make sure to request authorization in viewWillAppear: or later, and make sure to store a reference to your CLLocationManager. If you don't it will get deallocated and the dialog disappears.

Comment: Can even add it in viewDidLoad:, but its important to keep a reference to CLLocationManager.

Comment: So (just for the sake of completeness), for keeping a reference, I used a property with a strong modifier: `@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;`

Comment: Holy cats, @robotspacer. I am so glad you commented. I was doing everything except I had a local reference to locationManager since I'm using a MapView and only needed the location manager to request permissions. I never would have guessed I need to hang on to that reference.

Answer (score 10):

iOS 8.3, Xcode 6.3.1, ARC enabled

The question has been resolved, but I have (2) notes to add from my recent involvement with CLLocationManager.

1) You must have the following keys entered into your *.plist file:

[image]

Most commonly used keys have generic more descriptive names, such as "Privacy - Location Usage Description", which really is the "NSLocationUsageDescription" key.

To see the "raw" key names go to "*-Info.plist" and right click in the Navigator area where the keys are listed, see below:

[image]

And you get the following results:

[image]

The three keys that are related to this article are:

[image]

2) Make certain that you allocate and initialize your implementation of CLLocationManager before you try to request authorization or update location.

*.h file:

```
@interface SomeController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

*.m file:

```
- (IBAction)locationButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (self.locationManager == nil)
    {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    }
    else
    {
        nil;
    }

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    else
    {
        nil;
    }

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Hope this saves someone time!  Thanks.

Comment: Please leave the blank ...else statements in, that is my programming style, be it right or wrong it helps me keep things organized in my mind.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little gotcha. Make sure you're adding the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription keys to the main bundle plist and not one of your test target plists!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem caused because I was instantiating `CLLocationManager` in a local var inside a method, solved it making the `CLLocationManager` a class property.
After a while I found the solution here, but I'm leaving it here since this is the first result in google, hope I save you some time:

[requestWhenInUseAuthorization() not Work in iOS 8 With NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription Key in Info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681951/requestwheninuseauthorization-not-work-in-ios-8-with-nslocationwheninuseusaged)

Answer (score 0):

Pertaining to the Apple Watch:

You need to put the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` key in the iPhone's `Info.plist`, not the WatchKit App's.

This has bitten me twice now.