# My app crashes immediately after startup

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

As it's in tittle written, my app crashes immediately after it's startup. I really don't know, what to do. Thanks for any help. Here is code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import CoreLocation;

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *location;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *date;
@end

@implementation ViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    //date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, YYYY"];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
    self.date.text = (@"%@", dateString);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
    self.location.text = (@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
}

@end
```

After crash it shows this:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0eVO.png

Comment: Can you show us what is printed in the debugger ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850128/ios-8-requestwheninuseauthorization-no-popup ?

Comment: hook up lldb and check the back trace

Comment: apply exception break point....and also check if you are storing any value to userdefault then it should not be null while starting app and evolving userdefault

Comment: are you sure this class what cause your app crash?!

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete can you check it out and post once again

You have got

```
@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)
```

and you have not set function  `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`

Inside which method are you placing this below code. You have placed it below viewDidLoad but it isnot inside any methods. Check your code properly

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

 //date
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, YYYY"];

 NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
 NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
 self.date.text = (@"%@", dateString);
}
```

Comment: I was confused as well, but it was just a formatting issue, the code is actually right and the regarding the selector: he has not to define it, he is calling it on the CLLocationManager, not on self

Comment: Everything worked fine, but after adding `self.date.text = (@"%@", dateString);` line it didn't work anymore. I tried to delete that line and ran again, but nothing worked.

Comment: Please delete this answer since it does not contain any relevant content

Answer (score 0):

apply exception breakpoint in your app and try again .It will tell you where exactly the crash is