# I am trying to fetch current location of user in iOS 8.4 but it is not work and I am use this code

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am using the below code for displaying the user current location in iOS 8.4.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
    {        
         [super viewDidLoad];

         [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
         self.mapView.delegate = self;
         [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
         locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
         locationManager setDelegate:self];
         [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
         [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    }
```

But it is not working properly. It displays the following error:

> Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location
>   authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager
>   requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager
>   requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 8 requestWhenInUseAuthorization no Popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850128/ios-8-requestwheninuseauthorization-no-popup)

Answer (score 0):

For get user current location you need add one key as string in your project info.plist file.

Key is : 
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription