# How to locate my current location in iOS?

Tags: ios, mapkit

i got this error what that error meant to be.i can't understand what error it is.

so plz help

thanks

error

[image]

1.**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mycurrentlocation;

@end
```

2. **ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController @synthesize mycurrentlocation;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.mycurrentlocation.delegate = self; }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    MKCoordinateRegion re = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800,
800);
    [self.mycurrentlocation setRegion:[self.mycurrentlocation regionThatFits:re] animated:YES];

    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"Where am I?";
    point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

    [self.mycurrentlocation addAnnotation:point]; }

@end
```

Comment: you need to have authorisations keys set in your plist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get current location from user in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios)

Comment: how can i give authorisation key set in my plist???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850128/ios-8-requestwheninuseauthorization-no-popup

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the core location framework and Map Kit framework.

In your AppName-Info.plist Add a new row with the key name being:

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

Or

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

With the value being a string of the message that you want to be displayed:

YourAppName would like to use your location.

In your header file. (I use App Name-Prefix.pch but YourViewController.h will work too)

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
```

YourViewController.h

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate,  CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

}


@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

YourViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    mapView.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
         // Use one or the other, not both. Depending on what you put in info.plist
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    #endif
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);

    //View Area
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLat {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLon {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceAlt {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.altitude];
}
```

Comment: Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

Comment: @ParagBharambe: what is your error can you send a screen shot of it.

Comment: Hey i had edited my question and added the screen shot of error just open that link u will find the screen shot

Comment: did you tried the code which I have written in the answer above?
If yes then my next question would be what is your x code version and if you are running your code in iphone then what is your ios version in the phone?

Comment: Apparently in iOS 8 SDK, requestAlwaysAuthorization (for background location) or requestWhenInUseAuthorization (location only when foreground) call on CLLocationManager is needed before starting location updates.

There also needs to be NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in Info.plist with a message to be displayed in the prompt. Adding these may solve your problem

Comment: You can also try:

         // Use one or the other, not both. Depending on what you put in info.plist
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
  
instead of :

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
         // Use one or the other, not both. Depending on what you put in info.plist
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    #endif

Comment: You could have also probably missed giving values to string NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Then put this line of code in the `viewDidLoad` method of your class:

```
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```